# Changing Executable Image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

How do you change the build executable image for your program? Right now mine looks like a blank form. I would like to add a custom image.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project, go to `Application` and press the `...` button towards the bottom of the screen.